# Send an asynchronous email

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I send an asynchronous email with rails 4? By that I mean, when I click the 'send' button of a contact form, the page doesn't refresh, but the email is validated and sent, and a message is flashed to the user.

I've configured `action_mailer` correctly, and have a `ContactForm` mailer with one `contact` action that takes an email address as a parameter.

As a result,

```
ContactForm.contact("test@gmail.com").delivers #=> delivers email perfectly
```

But that's working on the command line. I don't really know the correct way to do this with a link. I mean, I could create a button that naviagates to `send_email`, and then I could have a route like this:

```
get 'send_email', to: 'contact#sendemail'
```

Then I would have a sendemail action which contains this method chain as shown above. 
But this isn't asynchronous, and, also, I have no idea how I could validate the email's fields before sending the email, or highlighting invalid fields.

Is Ajax and JSON responses the key to highlighting the fields? What about the validation?

The `resque_mailer` seems to be a good way to send asyncronous emails. But why do I need this external gem when ajax is handled so well by vanilla rails?

Answer (score 0):

The concept would be to have the form submit remotely. i.e submit to a `create` method in `ContactsController`. The method would then call a worker (resque/sidekiq) to send the email.

The `create` action can also respond to json. The json, response can either be a success or a fail (with errors).

On the AJAX success callback, you can trigger an alert, display div, or whatever notifying the user that the email was sent.

If the json results are returned with erros, then you can display the error message via JS.

Answer (score 0):

This [Railscasts Episode #171](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job?view=asciicast) Demonstrates sending emails using a background process with the help of [DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)